# Laravel API : how to get only some fields and sort the response

Tags: laravel, api

I would like to know if I do the things correctly.

Let's say I have a table "countries". To get only some fields of this table, in a certain order, I have this url :

`/countries?fields=id,country_name&desc=country_name`

And the result is clear:

```php
[
    {
        "id": "SP",
        "country_name": "Spain"
    },
    {
        "id": "IT",
        "country_name": "Italy"
    },
    {
        "id": "FR",
        "country_name": "France"
    },
    {
        "id": "CN",
        "country_name": "China"
    } ]
```

To do that I have this route :

```php
Route::get('/countries', 'CountryController@index');
```

And the method index is :

```php
public function index(Request $request)
{
   
    $query = Country::query();
   
    if ($request->has('fields')){         
        $fields = explode(',', $request->input('fields') );          
        foreach ($fields as $field) {
            $query->addSelect($field);
        }        
    }
    
    if ($request->has('sort')){
        $query->orderBy($request->input('sort'));
    }
    
    if ($request->has('desc')){
        $query->orderBy($request->input('desc'), 'desc');
    }
   
    $countries = $query->get();
    
    return response()->json($countries, 200);
}
```

It works fine.

My question is am I doing the things correctly ? Is there any other methods ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent unknown column exception try this:

1. import Schema class `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;`
2. add this:

   ```
   $table = "countries";
   if ($request->has('fields')){
       $fields = explode(',', $request->input('fields') );
       foreach ($fields as $field) {
           if(!Schema::hasColumn($table,$field)){
               return response("Unknown field", 422);
           }
           $query->addSelect($field);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks Hussein. As I want to be more generic , I prefer to use this : if(Schema::hasColumn($table, $field)){ $query->addSelect($field); } .        like that it works with all tables I want.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing to me has no vulnerability in it and is very optimized too.

Comment: thanks for your feedback. But if the url contains an unknown column, then i have an exception. how to prevent that ? Does it mean I have to check if the column exists before doing the query ?

Comment: what you can do is to define a route that takes parameters.in that way a column can never be passed that doesnt exists

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this:

```
$countries = $query->pluck('id', 'country_name');
```

Please check and let me know.